# Ignoring strings without using the -v flag

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I am trying to use egrep to find lines in a file that contain a certain word, but dont start with that word.

I am currently doing as so...

```
egrep '^word|word' file.txt
```

I tried putting it in brackets with the ^ not symbol, but brackets specifiy each letter individually and not a word as a whole.

```
egrep'^[^word]|word' file.txt
```

How can I do this, to ignore a certain first word, for example I ignore every **The** that is at the beginning of a sentence but spot the other ones. Without using the v-flag.

Comment: try this - `cat file.txt | egrep 'word'`

Comment: I don't think it is possible with egrep without using -v option.. you could do if you have GNU grep with PCRE option

Comment: This works in finding the words in the file but I am still having trouble with trying not to read the word if it appears first on the line.

Comment: using the example from given answer, do you want `word some word` line to be shown or ignored when searching for `word`? this line starts with `word` but also has a `word` elsewhere in the line

Comment: I want the word at the beginning of the line to be ignored, but not the word further on in the line.

Comment: Try `grep -P '^(?!word).*word' file.txt`, with `egrep`, I doubt there is a sane solution.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is:

```
grep '..*word' file
```

or:

```
grep -E '.+word' file
```

to find lines that contain `word` at a location other than the start of a line.